# How to store the whole SMTP transcript, of sending one email, to a database?

Tags: php, symfony, email, smtp, postfix-mta

My Symfony application sends an email for a logged in user to another company.

```
user -> mypage -> email -> companyX
```

normally i just use swiftmailer for sending the email but in this case i need to store the whole SMTP transcript of sending te email to the database (per email) for confirmability.

i haven't found a way to get this information directly from swiftmailer or any other php mail lib. is there such a lib somewhere?

my approach would be to use the logs of the mta (postfix) and somehow parse the information and store it into database via cronjob.

is there an easier/better way for doing that?

this is such a example transcript:

```
telnet www.sample.com 25

Server Response: 220 www.sample.com ESMTP Postfix
Client Sending : HELO domain.com
Server Response: 250 Hello domain.com
Client Sending : MAIL FROM: <me@domain.com>
Server Response: 250 Ok
Client Sending : RCPT TO: <friend@sample.com>
Server Response: 250 Ok
Client Sending : DATA
Server Response: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Client Sending : Subject: Example Message
Client Sending : From: me@domain.com
Client Sending : To: you@sample.com
Client Sending :
Client Sending : Yo,
Client Sending :
Client Sending :   Sending a test message.
Client Sending :
Client Sending :   Later,
Client Sending : Carl
Client Sending : .
Server Response: 250 Ok: queued as 45334
Client Sending : QUIT
Server Response: 221 Bye
```

Comment: You will have to use the mail server logs.